# How to properly split a line in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am bit confused

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
        String s = "a,b,c,d,";

        System.out.println(s.split(",").length);
    }
```

I was expecting to see 5 as output.. but the output is 4?
Why does it ignores the last "null" field

How do I handle this case if I am trying to parse data which has (say) 5 columns.

```
cases:
a,b,c,d,e
a,,c,d,e //this case is fine as this still has 5 fields.. one of the field is missing.. but thats ok
a,b,c,d //simple length check with header catches this error
a,b,c,d,e,f //simple length check
a,b,c,d,e,// looks like there are 6 fields.. but unable to catch such error by length check
```

Comment: `null` string is different than empty("") string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method ignores any trailing empty string. So, they are not the part of the array. If you want them to be the part of array, use the overloaded [`split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method, which takes a limit as 2nd argument. If you pass a negative value for the limit, the trailing empty strings won't be ignored.

```
System.out.println(s.split(",", -1).length);
```

And also, an empty string is not `null`.

Comment: And also, an empty string is not `null`. Thanks for adding this.